# Is it possible to run cargo run with a specific version of my own binary?

Tags: rust

I'm building a pretty sizable project in Rust. I am finished with what I wish to label `v1.0`. The next version of my project will be a significant overhaul but for demonstration purposes, I would still like to be able to run `v1.0`.

I could always `git tag` my commit and then switch to that tag, but somehow to me, this seems like something Cargo *should* be able to do.

Is there a way I can do this, preferably using something along the lines of `cargo run v1.0`?

Comment: "but somehow this seems like something Cargo should be able to do." - I've never heard of a build system that can simply do that. I guess you could duplicate the code and use workspaces to have both versions side by side.

Comment: Following @SebastianRedl's suggestion, doing something like `git worktree add --detach demo v1.0 && cd demo && cargo run` should more or less do the trick.